# How to read character with scanf in C? Getting "spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]"

Tags: c

When I try to compile I get the following warnings:

> warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]
>
> warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Here's the bit that's causing problems:

> char drop, sub;
>
> printf("Please enter a character to be dropped.\n");
>
> scanf(" c%", &drop);
>
> printf("Please enter a character to be subbed.\n");
>
> scanf(" c%", &sub);

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `%` comes before `c`, not after.

Comment: typo I think.. it should be scanf(" %c",&drop);

Comment: Oh jesus I am an idiot, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%c", &drop);//---> correct usage
```

You are reading a character.

Passing the address of the character variable to the `scanf` function with proper format speicifier.